# Find if a number exists between a range of numbers specified by a list

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
timestamp_list = ['1377091800', '1377093000', '1377094500', '1377095500']
```

Target number:

```
ptime = 1377091810
```

I want to find between which pair of timestamp does `ptime` lie in. For e.g. in this case, it lies between the first and the second timestamp. So I want to return the value `1377091800` as the desired output.
Similarly, if `ptime` was `1377091520`, then I want the third timestamp to be returned i.e. `1377091500` since it lies between third and the fourth timestamp.

My code:

```
timestamp_list = ['1377091800', '1377093000', '1377094500', '1377095500']
ptime = 1377091810
for idx, value in enumerate(timestamp_list):
    val = long(value)
if idx!= len(timestamp_list)-1 and ptime >= val and ptime < long(timestamp_list[idx+1]):
    target = val
    break
elif (idx == len(timestamp_list)-1) and ptime >= val:
    target = val
else:
    pass
print target
```

Output:
`1377091800`

I wanted to know is there any elegant solution to this? Since I am just starting with python, I am not yet familiar with all the functions in python.

Comment: Is the timestamp list sorted?

Comment: Something like `[x for x in tsl if x <= ptime] [-1]`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes timestamp list is sorted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the timestamps are sorted, you can use [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) for that:

```
In [24]: timestamp_list = [1377091800, 1377093000, 1377094500, 1377095500]

In [25]: timestamp_list[bisect.bisect_right(timestamp_list, 1377093100)]
Out[25]: 1377094500
```

(I've converted the strings to integers to keep the code clear.)

Comment: Moreover, to use `bisect` you *have* to use integers as alphanumeric sorting of numbers is not necessarily the same as numeric sort, throwing `bisect` off for certain edgecases. Granted, for timestamps, you are unlikely to hit those, but still.

Comment: And for completeness sake (since I deleted my answer): `bisect` takes O(log N) time, versus O(N) for a full scan. In laymans terms: a heck of a lot faster.

Comment: I tweaked the above answer to suit my purpose. Since index returned by the `bisect` module was one more than the index required, I decremented it to get the desired output. Updating my question with the solution I used.

Answer (score 0):

```
import bisect
timestamp_list = ['1377091800', '1377093000', '1377094500', '1377095500']
ptime = str(1377093110)
if ptime in timestamp_list:
    target = ptime
else:
    index = bisect.bisect_right(timestamp_list, ptime)-1
    target = timestamp_list[index]
print target
```

gives the following output:

```
1377093000
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18551848/2) to the question [Find if a number exists between a range of numbers specified by a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551848/find-if-a-number-exists-between-a-range-of-numbers-specified-by-a-list) by the OP [Geekster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1319910/geekster) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>